# How do I automatically accept the "Open URL in <AppName>" prompt in an iOS simulator?

Tags: url, ios-simulator

I'm using `xcrun simctl openurl` from a script to automate opening my app to various locations, and take screenshots. However, the first time I use it on a new simulator, I get a prompt asking me to accept that this URL will open in my app. Is there a way to disable/skip this prompt?

Answer (score 4):

I found that the simulator stores this data in a file `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<udid>/data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.launchservices.schemeapproval.plist`

Look at that file to see the exact format of the key for your app, but for my app (called "mygame"), I was able to use PlistBuddy to modify this file before launching my app:

`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<udid>/data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.launchservices.schemeapproval.plist -c "clear dict" -c "add com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorBridge-->mygame string com.serpentisei.mygame"`

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a lifesaver that unblocked our E2E tests configuration!